# solidity global variables uint256 in division its not work

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

example:

```
uint256 unit = 10000000000000000 * (100 / 1000);
```

it is work.

global variables:

```
uint256 ratio = 100; //in global

uint256 unit = 10000000000000000 * (ratio / 1000); //in function
```

not work, the result always be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Solidity fractional division is not supported. As to how the division works you can refer to [the documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#rational-and-integer-literals). What is happening in your code is the result of the division rounding down to 0.

You can find information about how fixed point variables work in Solidity [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#fixed-point-numbers). You can try to use these but you should really try to avoid using fractional numbers in your code.

In your case you can replace the expression with `uint256 unit = 10000000000000000 / (1000 / ratio);` as long as `ratio < 1000`